# Node test is not running

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run following code===>

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' } };
var client = webdriverio.remote(options);

client
.init()
.url('http://www.webdriveruniversity.com/')
.click('#login-portal')
.getTitle().then(function(title) {
 console.log('Title is: ' + title);
 })
 .end();
```

The output I am getting as follows. Not sure how to solve it.

```
const remote = async function (params = {}, remoteModifier) {
                 ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\webdriverFramework\loginPortal
```

Test.js:1:81)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use a library that uses `async` functions with an old Node.js version that does not support them. Please, run `node -v` and compare the Node.js version with the [`async` functions support table](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated node but still having the same issue.  DEBUG wdio-config: @wdio/sync not found, runn
ing tests asynchronous
C:\Users\Adnan\Desktop\webdriverFramework\loginPortalTest.js:6
    .init()
     ^

TypeError: client.init is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Adnan\Desktop\webdriverFramework\l
oginPortalTest.js:6:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:7
00:10)

Comment: What version do you use now?

Comment: Node version -v10.15.1

Comment: But this does not look as the same issue: previously you had `SyntaxError` (the code was not even parsed and executed). Now you have runtime errors during execution. It is worth to create a new question for these errors.

Comment: Sure. I will create one. Thanks.